# iPhone GLU(OpenGL Utility Library)

Tags: opengl-es

This link says [iPhoneGLU](https://code.google.com/archive/p/iphone-glu/) says, this libraray supports below futures.

Matrix manipulation
Polygon tessellation

I would like to know whether I can use this library to draw primitives(lines,points,triangles,simple polygon).

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need GLU for that. You can just use straight OpenGL. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Library): "The GLU specification was last updated in 1998, and it depends on features which were deprecated with the release of OpenGL 3.1 in 2009."

Answer (score -1):

I personally like glad. The have an online generator as well http://glad.dav1d.de

It will generate exactly what you need for your platform.

Comment: glad loads function pointers. GLU includes utility functions for drawing. They're not comparable.